# Get Email Recipients in FlatFile SSIS Send Mail Task

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, msbi

I am new in using SSIS Mail Task or C# Script Task.
What I need is to send an email but the list of recipients (To and cc) should be read from a flat file.
Please give me some ideas how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No matter how new you are, you need to try something first. Does it _have_ to be a flat file? It's better to implement this in a project parameter.

Comment: how is the flat file going to get populated?

Comment: Doable, what have you tried and what challenges are you running into?  I'd start here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639668/ssis-get-data-from-a-flat-file-and-assign-to-variable, then in your for-each loop use the mail task and hook it up.   That's one solution.